# What is the correct syntax for accessing $PS1 and $HISTFILE environment variables within a zsh shell script?

Tags: shell, zsh

Why this doesn't work?

```
#!/bin/zsh
echo $PS1
```

or this

```
#!/bin/zsh
foo="$PS1"
echo $foo
```

I would like to use $PS1 and $HISTFILE variables inside a zsh script.
I read that that variable may be not automatically available since it is specific to the interactive shell environmen, but can't find a solid argument.

Comment: Only variables _exported to the environment_ are accessible to subprocesses; regular shell variables are process-local, so it's normal that programs you start can't see them (whether those programs are implemented as scripts is irrelevant; the `execv` boundary between process images doesn't care if before and after images are both shell interpreters: it replaces the process image regardless). If you ran `export PS1` in your interactive shell successfully, _that_ would make a noninteractive program you started from that shell be able to see the variable's value.

Comment: (However, it would cause other bugs, because it would mean that every child process would see that PS1 value, even if it wasn't zsh, so child processes running non-zsh interactive shells and inheriting your zsh-centric PS1 could have surprising behavior)

Comment: So there is no "correct syntax"; it's not data that exists at all in a noninteractive shell process (when not exported by a parent), choosing different syntax can't make it come out of nowhere. (You could source the script instead of running it as a shell process, of course).

Comment: Aside from the fact that I don't see a reason why `PS1`  should be put into the environment, you can do so. By default, they are only shell variables, and AFIK they are never set automatically - not even in interactive shells. You usually set them in one of the startup files for the shell.

Comment: In what way do you want to use `PS1`, a variable intended to support interactive shells, in a non-interactive shell?

Answer (score 0):

Since `PS1` is only set in an interactive shell, you could change the shebang to set the interactive flag:

```
#!/bin/zsh -i
echo $PS1
```

Note that this means that all other interactive shell properties also take effect, e.g. reading startup files for interactive shells. Maybe you could tell us why you want to access `PS1` in a script and then we might be able to offer a different solution.

A different strategy to get the values for `PS1` and `HISTFILE` might be to simply source the files where they are set. One crude approach could even be to grep some particular dot files in `$HOME`.